# r function to return column number

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(H0<-c(35.4, 36.0, 36.0, 36.4), H1<-c(34.2, 34.0, NA, NA), 
           H2<-c(33.4, 33.5, NA, 34.2), H3<-c(32.9, 33.0, 34.0, NA),
           H4<-c(32.8, 33.0, 33.5, 33.2))
```

I need to find the minimum value in each row which for the first row I do with:

```
min(df[1,], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Is there a function in r that will return the column number (5 in this case) rather than the actual value.

Comment: Yes: `which.min(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df<-data.frame(H0=c(35.4, 36.0, 36.0, 36.4), H1=c(34.2, 34.0, NA, NA), 
               H2=c(33.4, 33.5, NA, 34.2), H3=c(32.9, 33.0, 34.0, NA),
               H4=c(32.8, 33.0, 33.5, 33.2))
which.min(df[1,])
# H4 
#  5
```

Note: when you create your data frames with, e.g. `H0<-c(...)` instead of `H0=c(...)` you are also creating vectors `H0`, etc., and the column names will be incomprehensible.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `<-` vs `=` difference. One of the better examples of why they are not just interchangeable.

Comment: Maybe you should point out that `which.min` would only return one value even if there is more than one data point that qualifies as the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the column names for all the `min` values in a row

```
apply(df,1, function(x) {x1 <-x[!is.na(x)]; which(x1== min(x1))})
#   [[1]]
#   H4 
#   5 

# [[2]]
# H3 H4 
#  4  5 

# [[3]]
# H4 
#  3 

# [[4]]
# H4 
# 3
```